# No response on Ubuntu One Support

Tags: canonical, support

I submitted a support question to ubuntuone-support@canonical.com 6 days ago, received an automated response and nothing since. I have replied a few times looking for an update and nothing. This is very dis-heartening for a service that I am evaluating to pay for. Is this typical or is there some issue at the moment that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like we either didn't receive the request or missed it somehow. Sorry about that! That is not the usual experience with Ubuntu One customer service. You can contact me directly at joshua dot hoover at canonical dot com and I'll be sure to help you out.

Comment: I too unfortunately have not had any support for my issue within 9 days. May I contact you?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question. The folks here have the exact same interface to Ubuntuone as you do. I might suggest contacting http://www.canonical.com/ 
If you want to speak to someone right away, don't forget you can call us or write to us at one of our offices. Our London-based head office is a good place to start.

Canonical Group Limited
27th Floor, Millbank Tower
21-24 Millbank
London SW1P 4QP
United Kingdom

Main switchboard number: +44 20 7630 2400
Main fax number: +44 20 7630 2401